# Tool to open and close a session with matlab files

Tags: matlab, session, project

I work on several project with the matlab program, and for each project i have many matlab files that are opened. So, when i open matlab, all the matlab files from all project are present in the file list in the editor.

Do you now if there exist a tool/extension or whatever that is able to open/close a project session ? like visual basic or all the other programming software.

Thanks

Comment: [Changing the working directory](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) is the closest you'll get in MATLAB's IDE.

Comment: In addition to what @excaza said, you can install other editors (i.e. sublime text) that allow you to write matlab code and to better manage different projects.